# Chronological order of a sentence

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses

Would you say this sentence is grammatically incorrect in terms of chronological order? I somehow have the feeling it is.

> "When I finished reading Dracula, Mum had vacuumed the living room."

I think the subordinate clause should have happened first, however, the main clause contradicts this notion due to the use of past perfect.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: It might be odd stylistically, but looks fine to me grammatically. I would probably prefer _while_, or _by the time_ instead of _when_.

Comment: Depending on the context, it could be fine stylistically too.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine. *When* can mean either "at the time of" or "just after" (among other things).

1. *When I got up this morning, Leigh left.*
2. *When I got up this morning, Leigh was gone.*

In sentence 1, *when* means "just after". I got up this morning, whereupon Leigh left. I got up first.

In sentence 2, *Leigh was gone* asserts a state of affairs, not an action. I think that's what makes *when* mean "at the time of" here. At the time I got up, it was (already) the case that Leigh was gone.

The use of the past perfect makes your sentence more like sentence 2. At the time I finished reading, it was (already) the case that Mum had vacuumed the living room.

Answer (score 0):

Your instincts are correct: the sentence is grammatically incorrect.

There are several ways one could rewrite the sentence to make it correct. For example:

> ***"By the time I had finished reading Dracula, Mum had vacuumed the
>   living room."***

In this case, it is clear that I am comparing the time by which Mum had vacuumed the living room to the time I completed Dracula. Mum completed vacuuming *before* I finished reading Dracula. The chronological order makes sense.

> ***"At the same time I finished reading Dracula, Mum finished vacuuming
>   the floor."***

In this case, it is clear that I finished reading Dracula and Mum finished vacuuming at the same time. The chronological order is fine.

> ***"When I finished reading Dracula, Mum vacuumed the living room."***

In this case, it is clear that Mum vacuumed the living room *after* I finished reading Dracula. The chronological order is fine.

Given the above, what's wrong with the following???

> ***"When I finished reading Dracula, Mum had vacuumed the living room."***

What's wrong with it is that "When I finished reading Dracula" refers to a particular instant in time, whereas "Mum had vacuumed" refers to some time in the past. The chronological order is not fine.